# In ADO yaml pipelines, how can I extract a list of items to a reusable variable/parameter?

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

In my yaml delivery pipeline, I have multiple environments where I need to do a list of imports. The import list is identical between stages, so I end up with a step in each stage that says something like:

```
steps:
  - template: 'import_the_steps.yml'
    parameters:
      Endpoint: ${{ variables.StageEndpoint }}
      listofStepNames:
        - Foo
        - Bar
        - Fizz
        - Buzz
```

It would be really greaT to, instead of having to list each step name every stage, have a way to feed it in as one object that gets extrapolated - but I'm not sure how to do that or if it's even possible.

I tried searching after determining that there was no obvious list object type in yaml, and it looks like it's string: string mapping only on this front. Just hoping someone's come up with a solution/workaround for this kind of scenario.